# How can I use a variable to pick which column is selected?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can we use variable as column name ?

In my table days (MONDAY,TUESDAY..) are column names.

I want to get the DAY dynamically and use AS COLUMN NAME in my query.

My query :

```
SELECT EMP FROM SCHEDULE WHERE "DAY"(Dynamically I want) =1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't use variables to change the actual text of the queries. variables can be used just in place of literal values (dates, strings, times, numbers) but they can't change the text of the actual command.

The technical reason is that (oversimplyfying the things) oracle FIRST parses the text, establishes an execution plan and only after this considers the values of the variables.  more or less you can think (**this is just an analogy, of course, it is not really the same thing!**) that oracle "compiles" the queries like an C++ compiler compiles the source code of a function: it is not possible to pass a c++ procedure a variable that modifies the text of the procedure itself.

what you have to do is to rethink your approach taking in consideration what I just said:

```
     SELECT EMP FROM SCHEDULE 
      WHERE  
          (case :DAY_I_WANT 
               WHEN 'MONDAY' then -- 'MONDAY' is the string value of the variable :DAY_I_WANT
                  monday  -- monday, here is the column whose value I want CASE to return
               WHEN 'TUESDAY' then tuesday
               ...
               ...
               WHEN 'SUNDAY' then sunday
          end) = 1
```

keep in mind that this solution will not take advantage on any index on the MONDAY..SUNDAY columns. the best approach would be to create a different data structure where you have a separate row for each day and a proper dayofweek column. If you do this, you will be able able to write:

```
   select EMP from schedule
   where schedule.DAY = :DAY_I_WANT
```

and it will allow you to create an index on the DAY column, speeding up searches.

Having a separate column for each day equals to be looking for troubles.

Comment: Assuming this is actually in a PL/SQL procedure, you *could* use dynamic SQL to change the actual text of the query; but using case is better anyway of course.

Comment: Actually the best approach in pl/sql would be to write a function that opens and returns a different cursor depending on the value of dayofweek. This would take advantage of indexes and would avoid dynamic sql (which is prone to hyde syntax errors until runtime)...  But i am not sure he is talking about a query that will be executed within a plsql procedure...